# How do I join a many-faced mesh to a mesh with fewer faces?

Tags: modeling

I was trying to follow the famous [Coffee Cup Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y__uzGKmxt8).  However, I wanted to make a more realistic, curvy handle, rather than a square one.  However, I end up with this situtation:

[image]

I simply don't know any good ways of connecting objects with such different geometries.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: As an aside, the square handle is nice and curvy at the end anyway due to the subsurf modifier, you didn't necessary need to go this way.

Comment: Do you specifically want the geometries of the two edge loops to match? Or, are you ok with simply joining the two meshes?

Answer (score 12):

You can use **Bridge** tool.

- Select the two loops you want to connect;
- Press <kbd>W</kbd>, choose *Bridge Edge Loops* in the popup menu. More options for Bridge tool can be found in <kbd>F6</kbd> menu.

[image]

---

**P.S.** However, such topology may not benefit Surface Subdivision. So, it's recommended to have even subdivision level for both cup and handle. Suggested workflow would be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Union Boolean Modifier

You do not specify for certain in your question if you **require** the geometry of the two edge loops to match. With this in mind, if you **do** want the geometries to match, use Leon's *Bridge Edge Loops* answer. However, if you are ok with the geometeries *not* matching, then one very easy way to do this is to join the handle and the cup with a [*Boolean* modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Booleans) set to *Union*. This method does not create new faces on the cup joining to each face of the handle. Nonetheless, it still will join the two. Here's how:

1. If your handle is a Curve object (rather than a mesh object), then convert it to a mesh object:
   Select handle → <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> → *Convert to Mesh*
2. Position the handle and the cup together like you'd like them to be joined.
3. Add a *Boolean* modifier to the cup:
   Select cup → *Object Properties* window → *Modifiers* tab → *Boolean*
4. For Boolean's options:

   - Set *Operation* to *Union*
   - Set *Object* to the cup handle
5. Click the *Apply* button on the Boolean modifier and now the two will be joined:

   [image]