# How can I automatically create edges according to the number of vertices?

Tags: modeling

I wanted to create edges between these vertices automatically:

[image]

But when I selected all these vertices and pressed <kbd>F</kbd> this is what i got:

[image]

To create edge between each vertex I selected 3 or 4 vertices at a time and then I pressed <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

And I did the same for all:

[image]

So is their any shortcut method to do this?

Comment: Have you tried **W** > **Bridge Edge Loops**? Another answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9340/696) FYI.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a couple options:

## Triangulate:

Press <kbd>F</kbd> with everything selected to make an n-gon, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to triangulate it:

[image]

## Bridge:

As [Leon Cheung already mentioned](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9373/how-to-create-automatic-edges-according-to-number-of-vertex#comment15255_9373), you can use the bridge tool.

Select the opposite edge loops (in this case, everything) and press <kbd>W</kbd>*> Bridge edge loops* or <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.

[image]

This method will create quads if the the edge loops have the same vertex count but otherwise creates triangles. You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to automatically convert some of the tris to quads.

## Fill:

*You might already know this, but I thought I'd mention it just in case.*

[Fill now automatically detects vertices](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Usability_tools#Modeling) for the new faces, so to do what you did in your question you only have to select two vertices and then repeatedly press <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also enable the preinstalled F2 addon. Then after "filling" to verts to an edge you can "fill" the edge with <kbd>F</kbd>. Then the addon adds automaticly a quad face in the direction of your mouse.
(With this addon you have a few more options like filling a single point in a mesh etc)