# How to connect faces between 2 edge loops?

Tags: modeling, mesh, knife-tool

I'm trying to fill empty space in my mesh, and I looked at the knife tool page on the Blender Wiki, and I'm not sure if there's a way to make it so that a new edge is made using the knife tool. I took a screenshot, and hopefully it'll explain better than I can of what I'm trying to do. Oh and I'm using Blender version 2.71, by the way.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: read this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9373/how-can-i-automatically-create-edges-according-to-the-number-of-vertices/9375#9375

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In your particular situation, it looks like the bridge tool is what you want. Select two or more edge loops with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>, and then connect them with <kbd>W</kbd>*>Bridge Edge Loops*:

[image]

## Fill

To do exactly what it looks like you are trying to do in your screenshot (connecting two vertices with an edge), select the two vertices and press <kbd>F</kbd> to create edge/face.

[image]

If you have the bundled [F2 addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/mesh/f2.html#f2) enabled you can create a new face from the selected edge and the surrounding vertices by pressing <kbd>F</kbd> again. The side on which the new face is created is controlled by the cursor position.

## Knife

The knife tool is for cutting edges into existing faces:

[image]

Comment: Did you manually select those vertices in the last gif? If not would you mind telling me what key you held down before selecting multiple vertices at once?

Comment: @Marie Click Alt+RMB to select edge loops. For more info: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Selecting/Edges

Comment: @Marie `Alt Shift RMB` to select multiple loops (`Shift` maintains the existing selection)

Comment: This answer would be better if it noted bridge first (since this answers the question)

Comment: Do note that in the second gif the [F2 addon](https://sites.google.com/site/bartiuscrouch/scripts/f2) is enabled.

Comment: @David Good catch, I thought that I was using the F2-like behavior [which was added in 2.67](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Usability_tools#Modeling), but it seems that it's not working in this case? (bug?)

Comment: @ideasman42 Good point. Reformatted, hopefully it's easier to parse now.

Comment: I hope I don't add to the confusion here with more F2 talk.  You're correct that the F2 Addon is not necessary anymore for that behavior.  However, I found that it works best when in Edge-Mode.  Repeatedly filling in faces like that using Vertex Mode was buggy for a long time and maybe still is so I always do that in Edge mode which seems much more consistent and stable.

Answer (score 1):

[image]In Blender 2.8+ right click and the specials menu appears (no longer 'W' shortcut).