# How to join vertices of 2 separate parts of one object

Tags: modeling

I have 1 object, with 2 separate parts. How do I connect the vertices to basically create a bridge joining the two? Contrl + J does not work.

[image]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14969/how-to-connect-faces-between-2-edge-loops ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to use is **F**.  Select the vertices you want to join and hit **f**.  Ctrl + J is for joining two different **objects** together, not individual mesh components.

Comment: Ok. Just realized that only works with 4 vertices at a time (2 from each each sphere) When I first tried F, I had selected 4 vertices on each sphere (8 total) and clicked F and it did not fill. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Select the faces of the areas you want to connect then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and select **Bridge Edge Loops** from the menu.