# How Would I Join The Selected Edges Together

Tags: modeling

As you can see the lines are not the same, on the bottom it has bigger spaces and on the top its smaller, please help me out i tried everything i know and am stuck.[image]

Comment: If you have enough endurance and persistence, you could fill (F) every space.

Comment: There are several, almost infinite, ways in which the profiles can be joined. Some maximize certain properties and some not... What's the topology you are looking for? Could you sketch a small sample or describe it? And how many vertices are there for each circle?

Comment: @Bradman175 Bad idea. Since the loops don't all line up, there would be lots of irregularities from triangles.

Comment: @TARDISMaker I'm aware of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect faces between 2 edge loops?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14969/how-to-connect-faces-between-2-edge-loops)

Comment: @Bradman175 You do realize that because of that it won't turn out correctly, right? (and if you did, why suggest it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I am not aware of an automagic way to do this, but here is a workaround: In edit mode, select one edge segment from the lower piece and the corresponding edge segment from the upper piece. Use [F] to fill a face between them. Continue doing this around the model. Because of the difference in vertex count, you will occasionally need to fill a triangle instead of a quad.</s>

Here is some information on filling faces in edit mode:
https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/creating_faces_and_edges.html

Edit: Filling faces is still useful, but Bridge is way better.

In edit mode, you'll select the edge loops, then Mesh > Edges > Bridge Edge Loops. Here's some information on edge tools—scroll down to the Bridge section: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html

Comment: Although this would work, I think the OP is looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: Edited to add better way.

Answer (score 0):

What i had done was quite stupid, what i did was a quick remodel of that bottom part, and somehow i managed to fix it a little, as you can see in the picture there's one spot that is not like the others. if someone knows how to fix that pls help me out again.[image]

Comment: It looks like the vertex count is still a little off, causing that triangulated area (unless it also looks like that on the other side, but going the other way). One approach might be to bridge half the circumference and then bridge the rest in a second pass. This won't solve a count mismatch, but it will give you some control over where the triangulation occurs.