# How can i fill the U shape face/edge so there will be no empty space?

Tags: modeling

This is my U shape:

[image: U shape]

And this is how it should be:

It should be filled:

[image: U shaped filled]

I tried in edit mode to select with B some of the faces then i did in the menu under Extrude: Make Edge/Face but it didn't fill anything and not the whole U shape.

Comment: It's likely you want to use Bridge Edge Loops tool to quickly generate faces between 2 edge loops. Note - it could be more efficient to go with less edges. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14969/how-to-connect-faces-between-2-edge-loops

Comment: @daniel llee see my revised answer

Comment: @m.ardito I saw your edit. Thank you very much.

Comment: @daniel llee and I edited it again :D because cegaton pointed out another good method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if I missed something but have you tried classic <kbd>F</kbd> key to fill faces? Like

[image]

edit:

the above is the simplest, but gives you N-gons.

To fill with better topology, try <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>:

[image]

Then, if you need quads, simply convert with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>:

[image]

edit2:

cegaton commented about another smart tool, "bridge edge loops"

he's right, so you can also use that like this (note I used it *before* filling the side faces, otherwise it gave an error):

[image]

and you get immediately

[image]

Comment: **Bridge edge loops** would be a better tool for this, keeping it all as quads.

Comment: @cecgaton thanks, I added some reference to that, too. Although it needs to be used before filling side faces, or it gives "select at least two edge loops"