# How do I make a face between the inside of an outer mesh with the outside of an inner mesh?

Tags: vertices, faces

I have a racetrack in the middle of a bounding area.  I would like to join the two meshes and make faces between the square bounding area and the outside of the racetrack.

I have the relevant vertices of the racetrack saved as a vertex group.

[image: how to make faces]

Here is my blend file if it is required...

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GRYeYtInmAWoMQLOpG7K8Kaey_M7QNEi)

Or perhaps there is a better approach.  My ultimate goal is to have a plane outside the racetrack that will anchor objects for scenery in a video game.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not quite clear what faces should be filled and what are counterparts of selected edges, but try using Bridge Edge Loops, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14969/how-to-connect-faces-between-2-edge-loops

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it by selecting the vertex group with the outer 4 vertices of the bounding box and then `Mesh -> Faces -> Fill` or `Alt F` to "Fill a selected edge loop with faces".  I'm still open to a solution that is more correct.