# Creating faces between vertexes faster

Tags: modeling, faces, vertex-groups

Sometimes, I have to remake a set of faces for an object. E.g.

[image]

Is there a faster way to create faces between the outer and inner ring only (no center) than by selecting every four adjacent vertexes and creating a face between them?

Comment: Select all verts, then Alt+F for "Fill", then Alt+J for "Tris to Quads" I think.

Comment: F2 addon can help too.

Comment: Go into edge mode, Shift Alt Select both loops, shift deselect one opposing edge in each ring then right-click and Bridge Edge Loops.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14969